# C and the <complex.h> file

Tags: gcc, c-header

My simple program compTest.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<complex.h>

int main(void)
{
    double complex z = 1.0 + 1.0 * I;

    printf("|z| = %.4f\n", cabs(z));

    return 0;
 }
```

When using the  standard library and compiling with gcc on a Linux system do I need to include the -lm  flag for it to work?

Example:

```
gcc -o executableName fileName.c -lm
```

When I don't I get the following:
    /tmp/cc1o7rtt.o: In function `main':

```
comTest.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `cabs'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've already discovered that the answer is yes.

The `-lm` flag tells the linker to link the math library, which contains, among other things, the code for the `cabs` function. (This is a gcc/Linux issue, not a C language issue.)

The Linux man page for `cabs` specifically says `Link with -lm.`

(In general, if you want to call *any* library function and you're not 100% certain how to use it, read the man page.)

Comment: I read the man page but I seemed to have missed the part where it says "Link with  -lm'.  The first place I always go is to the man page.  Then Google.  Then if I can't find something remotely similar I come here.  Thanks for the info.